# team viewer 8 beta wont run

Tags: teamviewer

I installed teamviewer 7 and then one of my friend using windows got version 8 so I installed the beta of version 8 for Linux. When I try to run it from terminal I got these errors:

```
conner@DemonicGrace:~$ teamviewer

Init...
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer...
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
err:winedevice:ServiceMain driver L"MountMgr" failed to load
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP libgnutls not found, SSL connections will fail
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:resource:GetGuiResources (0xffffffff,0): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32df64,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x32dc1c,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x32df64,0x00000000), stub!
```

please help me out if anyone has ideas I am more than willing to listen.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the 32 bit verison of libgnutls26.

```
apt-get install libgnutls26:i386
```